# Rsync changed files on server

Tags: rsync

I have a rsync client which pushes all changes to the server. Suppose I change already existing copy on the server and do a rsync from my rsync client. The client is not updating the changed copy in the server i.e. it is unable to see the change i have made in the server.

I am using rsync with the following options:

```
-progu
```

How to make the client see the changed copy and update it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use different terms.  *Source* and *Target* make more sense for this.  You have a server that is normally your *Target*.  Now you've made changes to files on the server that you'd like reflected in *Source*.

What you're asking to do is reverse the roles of Source and Target in order to update this file.

The `-u` option already tells rsync "*skip files that are newer on the receiver*".  So you may be safe if you simply run an rsync in the other direction -- from your tradition target to your traditional source.  Files that are newer on your "client" won't be updated (because of `-u`); only the file that is newer should be updated.

Test this with `-v -n` options before running it "for real".